# TCP Echo server that only echoes first packet (C Language)

Tags: c, tcp, network-programming

I wrote some code in C for a TCP Server that echoes whatever it gets. The problem is when I send data first time it echoes it and next times the server sends back the first packet I sent. The log looks like:

```
Client Send : Packet1
Server reply : Packet1
Client Send : Packet2
server reply : Packet1
```

The server code is as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
int listenfd,connfd;
pid_t childpid;
socklen_t clilen;
struct sockaddr_in servaddr,cliaddr;
listenfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
printf("Socket listenfd : %d    with %d And %d\n",listenfd,AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM);
bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
servaddr.sin_port = htons(SERV_PORT);
printf("Server address: %d\n",servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr);
bind(listenfd, (SA*) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
printf("Listened: %d\n",listenfd);
listen(listenfd,LISTENQ);
printf("After Listening: %d\n",listenfd);
int num=0;
for( ; ; ){
    clilen=sizeof(cliaddr);
    connfd = accept(listenfd, (SA*) &cliaddr,&clilen);
    printf("Client no. %d connected\n",++num);
    if( (childpid=fork())==0){
        close(listenfd);
        echo(connfd);
        exit(0);
    printf("Client no. %d Terminated\n",++num);
    }
   close(connfd);
}
return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

And my echo function:

```
void echo(int sockfd) {
 ssize_t n;
 char    buf[MAXLINE];
 again:
 while ( (n = read(sockfd, buf, MAXLINE)) > 0)
     writen(sockfd, buf, n);
if (n < 0 && errno == EINTR)
     goto again;
 else if (n < 0)
     printf("read error");
}
```

the client code main :

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
int sockfd;
struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

sockfd= socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
bzero(&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));

servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
servaddr.sin_port= htons(SERV_PORT);
inet_pton(AF_INET,"0.0.0.0",&servaddr.sin_addr);
printf("%d , %d \n",sockfd,servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr);
connect(sockfd, (SA*) &servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
printf("%d\n",sockfd);
replyBack(stdin,sockfd);

printf("RETURN\n");
return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

the replyBack function:

```
void replyBack(FILE *fp, int sockfd) {
char sendline[MAXLINE], recvline[MAXLINE];
printf("ENTER  YOUR ECHOED:  \n");
while (fgets(sendline, MAXLINE, stdin) != NULL) {
    write(sockfd, sendline, sizeof(sendline));

    if (read(sockfd, recvline, MAXLINE) == 0)
    {
        printf("str_cli: server terminated prematurely");
        exit(-1);
    }
    fputs(recvline, stdout);

}
}
```

Comment: Your client and server work perfectly fine for me.  Check to make sure that none of the system calls you're making (`read`, `write`, `connect`, etc.) are returning errors or smaller-than-expected values.  Try using Wireshark to see what's actually getting sent across the network, which will tell you if the problem is on the client or the server.  Try using `netcat` as a replacement client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, let's look at this section of your code:

```
printf("After Listening: %d\n",listenfd);
int num=0;
for( ; ; ){
    clilen=sizeof(cliaddr);
    connfd = accept(listenfd, (SA*) &cliaddr,&clilen);
    printf("Client no. %d connected\n",++num);
    if( (childpid=fork())==0){
        close(listenfd);
        echo(connfd);
        exit(0);
    printf("Client no. %d Terminated\n",++num);
    }
   close(connfd);
}
```

Calling `exit` exits your application, so the `printf` following it will never get executed. Minor, but worth pointing out.

Also, in the "child" process, you should not close your listening socket. The only socket it should work with is the client connection, so you should have something more along the lines of:

```
if ( (childpid = fork ()) == 0 ) {
  echo ( connfd );
  close ( connfd );
  printf ( "Client no %d terminated.\n", num ); /* Don't use the ++ here or your count will be off */
  exit ( 0 );
}
```

Now let's look at your echo code:

```
void echo(int sockfd) {
  ssize_t n;
  char    buf[MAXLINE];
  again:
  while ( (n = read(sockfd, buf, MAXLINE)) > 0)
      writen(sockfd, buf, n);
 if (n < 0 && errno == EINTR)
      goto again;
 else if (n < 0)
      printf("read error");
}
```

Have to remember that the calls to `read` and `write` may block (since I don't see you setting the socket to non-blocking IO), and `write` may not send the entire buffer when called, so you need to check a few more things here.

```
void
echo ( int sockfd )
{
  ssize_t bytes_in, bytes_out, bytes_remaining;
  int write_err;
  char buf[MAXLINE];
  char * send_start_pos;
  while ( 1 ) {
    bytes_in = read ( sockfd, buf, MAXLINE );
    if ( bytes_in < 1 ) {
      if ( errno == EINTR )
        continue;
      break; /* other error occurred, or EOF (0 bytes read) */
    }
    bytes_remaining = bytes_in;
    send_start_pos = buf;
    write_err = 0;
    while ( ( bytes_remaining > 0 ) && !( write_err ) ) {
      bytes_out = write ( sockfd, send_start_pos, bytes_remaining );
      if ( bytes_out < 0 ) {
        if ( errno == EINTR )
          continue;
        write_err = 1;
        break;
      }
      bytes_remaining -= bytes_out;
      send_start_pos += bytes_out;
    }
    if ( write_err )
      break;
  }
}
```

Once your `echo` function exits, the socket will be closed back in the calling function. Generally, I would suggest closing the socket in the `echo` function, unless you need it afterwards. I almost certainly would suggest closing it when an error occurs, but, again, that is up to you.

Just as an aside, stay away from `goto` ... it has its purposes, but for the most part, well-written code rarely ever uses it.

Comment: it worked :) thanks very much for the solution and ur precious advices :D

Comment: Another minor remark: you should also check to see if `fork()` returns -1, which indicates an error.

Comment: @Adam: most definitely. good practice is to check for -1, 0, and anything else; was not focusing on that, so I missed that tweak.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem is that you're treating TCP as if it were a datagram protocol, which it isn't. It is a stream protocol.

<strike>I am yet to put my finger on what exactly is going on, but right now my money is on the client printing the message it already has in its buffer (as opposed to getting it the second time). Show us the client code.</strike>

**Edit** There are multiple things that are wrong.

First of all, a single call to `write` may require multiple calls to `read` on the other end.

Secondly, since TCP is a stream protocol you need to make sure that for every logical message the receiving side knows how many bytes to expect. You either need to stick to fixed-length messages or prefix each message with its length. You're kind of doing the former by always sending `MAXLINE` bytes, but not quite consistently enough (for example, `writen(sockfd, buf, n)` writes `n` bytes back, and `n` can be different from `MAXLINE`).

**Another edit** to address a point made in the comments. `Telnet` is a bad analogy: in `telnet`, there is a *stream* of characters flowing one way, and a *stream* of characters flowing the other way. In your protocol you're sending discrete multibyte *messages* (or *datagrams*). This is precisely the reason why you're finding a datagram protocol (UDP) easier to apply to your problem.

Comment: You can use telnet as a client..but ok i will edit the post and add the client

Comment: Doesn't matter if you're using telnet as a client, it's still a stream.